# Comparing keys of a multi-dimensional HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, multidimensional-array

I am working on an application with a number of custom data classes. I am taking input for my application from 2 different places and want to cross-reference between the two to help ensure the data is accurate.

I have a `Map.Entry<String,HashMap<String, Integer>>` object called `chromosome`, where each value is called a `marker`.

I also have a custom object called `IndividualList individuals` which extends `HashMap<Integer,Individual>` where each `Individual` has a method `Genotype getGenotype()` which returns the non-static variable `genotype`. `Genotype` extends `HashMap<String,String[]>`

I want to look at each the `key` for all my `marker` objects and check whether each of them are present as a key in *any* `Individual`'s `genotype`. Every `Individual` has the same keys in its `genotype` so I only need to test for one `Individual`.

The problem I am facing is which `Individual` to test, as because it is a `HashMap` I cannot simply just arbitrarily choose the first element, so what I am doing at the moment is taking the values of `individuals` as a `Collection` then converting these to an `ArrayList<Individual>` then taking the first of these elements (which is just an arbitrary one as `HashMap` is unordered) to get an `Individual` then taking this `Individual`'s `genotype` and comparing `marker.getKey()` with the keys in the `genotype`. Like so :

```
for(Map.Entry<String, MarkerPosition> marker : chromosome.getValue().entrySet())
    if(!(new ArrayList<Individual>(individuals.values()).get(0)
                    .getGenotype().containsKey(marker.getKey())))
            errors.add("Marker " + marker.getKey() + " is not present in genotype");
```

But as you can see, this is horrid and ugly and far too complicated, so I was wondering if there is a much simpler way of achieving what I want that I am missing.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you save a reference to the `Individual` object you pick before you start the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can you not arbitrarily choose the first element of a HashMap?

```
individuals.entrySet().iterator().next()
individuals.values().iterator().next()
```

This will probably be the same entry each time.  You should make sure the map is not empty to avoid an exception.

Answer (score 0):

...This question is really confusingly phrased and difficult to understand, but I'm not clear on why you don't just use

```
 individuals.values().iterator().next()
```

instead of `new ArrayList<Individual>(individuals.values()).get(0)`.

(If you can use third-party libraries, your code would probably be significantly clearer overall if you used a Guava [`Table`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table), which is a general-purpose, significantly "cleaner" replacement for a `Map<K1, Map<K2, V>>`.  Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)